# Popular um select com resultado php utilizando jQuery e cakephp

Tags: jquery, cakephp, select

Olá, estou tentando popular um select com as opções que são retornadas, de acordo com o que o usuário seleciona em um determinado select.
O problema é que sou leigo com jquery e não sei se estou fazendo isso corretamente.

No meu select eu chamo a função com o evento onchange:

`<?=$this->Form->input('escola_id',array('class'=>'formcontrol','onchange'=>'MostraPrograma(this.value)'));?>`

Como eu só quero tratar este select específico, eu dou um `$.post` em uma url onde ela faz a consulta de acordo com a opção selecionada.

```
function MostraPrograma(_a){
 $.post('/novas/mostra_programa/'+_a), $("#CursoNewAddForm").serialize(),function(data){

 }
```

}

e na minha view eu faço isso:

```
echo '_tipos_de_programa = ' . json_encode($info_campus).';';
```

e no meu console me retorna este array:

```
_tipos_de_programa = [{"CursoCampus":{"id":"21","nome":"Curso Geral 35 aulas 221232"}},{"CursoCampus":{"id":"22","nome":"Curso Geral 35 aulas 221"}},{"CursoCampus":     {"id":"23","nome":"Curso Geral 25 aulas12323"}}];
```

Agora como faço para popular com este resultado, o select com id `curso_nome`?

Espero que tenha explicado bem minha dúvida.